# Как отличать обстоятельственное определение от обстоятельства?

Tags: определение

Сияние звёзд на тёмном небе. 
Почему *на тёмном небе* не является обстоятельством, а обстоятельственным определением?

Значит, это назывное предложение?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сияние звёзд на тёмном небе. Что? -Сияние-подлежащее.

Какое сияние? звёзд -несогласов.определение с добавочным значением дополнения(чего?-звёзд)

Звёзд каких?-на небе-обстоятельственное несоглас.определение. Почему  не  обстоятельство? Потому что обстоятельство обозначает различные условия совершения действия и относятся к сказуемому, а его здесь нет.Это бытийное назывное предложение, сообщающее о том,что существует сияние.Всё остальное - распространение, определения к подлежащему.

Вот если бы мы вынесли НА НЕБЕ в начало предложения, это был бы обстоятельственный детерминант: (Где?)На тёмном небе что происходит? - сияние звёзд. Здесь подразумевается действие, глагол, на его наличие указывает обстоятельство. Так различаются неполные двусоставные (эллиптические) и односоставные назывные. Поздний вечер - назывное. Вечер поздний - неполное двусоставное.

В синем небе коршуны .-в небе-обстоятельство, потому что оно указывает на место обитания коршунов. Ему нравились коршуны в синем небе .- в небе- определение, потому что оно определяет существительное(дополнение)коршуны.Какие коршуны?- в синем небе=которые обитают в синем небе.

Answer (score 2):

"Сияние звёзд на тёмном небе". Это назывное предложение.  "На темном небе сияние звезд". Это эллиптическое предложение (возможна постановка тире).

ПРАВИЛО

Эллиптическими называются двусоставные предложения особого построения, состоящие из подлежащего и дополнения или обстоятельства (сказуемое в таких предложениях всегда отсутствует). Эллиптические предложения следует отличать от сходных с ними по структуре назывных предложений, в которых вторая часть является не обстоятельством, а обстоятельственным определением.

КАК ОТЛИЧИТЬ

У эллиптических и назывных предложений разная семантика и обычно разная структура.

НАЗЫВНЫЕ(номинативные) предложения сообщают о наличии предмета в поле зрения наблюдателя  (это особый изобразительный прием). Существительное, обозначающее предмет, может быть распространено определением, в том числе несогласованным (обстоятельственным).

В ЭЛЛИПТИЧЕСКИХ предложениях обстоятельство обозначает пространство, в котором существует объект.

По структуре в эллиптических предложениях на первом месте обычно находится обстоятельство, а на втором подлежащее, а у назывных обстоятельственное определение следует за определяемым существительным.

В то же время можно представить такой парный вариант: "цветы - в вазе" и "цветы в вазе",
например: (1) Повсюду цветы: цветы - в вазе, цветы - в горшках. (2) Тишина. Белая скатерть, цветы в горшках.

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ ОТ 28.07.14 Г.

УТРО. ТИШИНА В ДОМЕ. Это назывное (односоставное бытийное) предложение.

Главный член выражен  именем существительным или словосочетанием в И.п. Номинативное предложения сообщают не просто о существовании предмета, но и о наличии этого предмета в поле зрения наблюдателя. Наблюдатель как бы переносится в тот момент времени, когда происходит событие и определяет его как происходящее «сейчас». Назывные предложения – это особый вид предложения, в котором нет сказуемого. Сказуемое обозначает процессуальный  (существующий во времени) признак, а  в назывном предложении такой процесс отсутствует – там называется предмет, который видит наблюдатель в фиксированный момент времени.

В ДОМЕ ТИШИНА. Это эллиптическое предложение, другой вид бытийных предложений (двусоставных).

В этих предложениях детерминант (обстоятельство)  обозначает пространство, в котором существует предмет в определенный отрезок времени, и наблюдатель фиксирует это существование.

Образно говоря, номинативное предложение -  это фотография, а  эллиптическое (двусоставное)  предложение – это съемка видеокамерой.

Answer (score 1):

http://rus.1september.ru/articlef.php?ID=200304608

Спорным остается вопрос о наличии в номинативном предложении таких второстепенных членов, которые имеют обстоятельственное или объектное значение и не образуют словосочетания с главным членом: В доме тишина; Сегодня экзамен; У меня радость и т.п. Форма этих членов предложения не мотивируется, не управляется главным членом – номинативом. Это служило поводом усматривать в таких предложениях пропуск сказуемого, к которому якобы относятся данные члены. Однако характеристика данных предложений как двусоставных неполных основана на «подразумевании» сказуемого. В действительности же значение бытия, наличия выражено в них номинативом. Эти предложения являются номинативными односоставными с второстепенными членами приосновного типа, которые имеют самостоятельное значение (пространственное, временное, субъектное и пр.). Эти члены как в двусоставных, так и в односоставных предложениях не являются зависимыми компонентами словосочетания; они поясняют предикативную основу в целом (ср.: В доме топились печи; В доме стало тепло; Сегодня я весел; У меня сын – студент).

выходит, что *В доме тишина* - это номинативное?
*И тишина в доме* - тоже номинативное?

Comment: Ну что Вы, это же Касаткин, вузовскиий учебник для учителей начальных классов, представляющий анализ русского языка для расширения общего кругозора,здесь даются ВСЕ точки зрения, и СПОРНЫЕ в том числе, с изложением его мнения. Здесь как раз речь идёт о детерминантах - не присловных членах предложения, а приосновных. Касаткин относит такой тип  предложений к односоставным предложениям, но академическая школьная грамматика - к двусоставным неполным. Разберитесь, что ВАМ нужно, - поддержать взгляд Касаткина или выполнить задание в соответствии с ОБЩЕПРИНЯТОЙ грамматикой

Comment: газета "1 сентября"поместила отрывок для ознакомления учителей с новым взглядом, для расширения кругозора, а не для следования его учебнику в практике обучения.